# Android Studio 0.8.14 can't find sdk

Tags: android, android-studio

I have upgraded to Android Studio 0.8.14 and moved my sdk folder as instructed (to ~/android-sdk). When I opened an old project, I was never prompted to update the sdk location, and Now my project has all these build errors like `package android.content does not exist`.

I have opened up Project Structure to try to correct the problem but I don't know what I'm doing in here and the [Android documentation](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio0814inbetachannel) of

> opening up the Project Structure Dialog and selecting the SDK Location
>   tab

is a little underwhelming. Below is a screenshot of my Project Structure where I have seemingly updated the sdk to the new correct location:

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong because I didnt have this problem but I think you need the `Default Project Structure` in `File/Other Setings/Default Project Structure` this is where you can change the SDK location for new and current apps

Comment: The `Default Project Structure` also shows my new sdk location already, and I still have the issue.

Comment: Did try "build>clean project"

Comment: Don't have a "clean project" option under build. Maybe because it is a non gradle project? Solved now though.

Comment: Solved? So it is working, do share how you were able to make it work.

Comment: @bond Already posted my answer below.

Comment: ahh, I wasn't refreshing fast enough :) Glad that its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to point my module's sdk to the new sdk I had just created:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First go to File -> Close project

On the new window that pops up go to Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure

At this window you can now set your SDK and JDK. Once you've set them you can go back and select your project from the list. Just remember when you re-open the project for the first time Android Studio will be indexing the "new" SDK directory so it may pause for a while

[image: Project Structure Window]

Comment: This didn't work for me (The sdk location here was already my new correct location)